# How to create a custom order status in woocommerce!

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I've tried the below code to create custom status.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $term = get_term_by( 'name', 'shipped', 'shop_order_status' );
    if ( ! $term ) {
        wp_insert_term( 'shipped', 'shop_order_status' );
    }
} );
```

But it is not working. I tried some other methods also. Please can anyone help me on this..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what I have used to create a custom order status called "Invoiced".
Add this to your theme's functions.php

```
// New order status AFTER woo 2.2
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_new_order_statuses' );

function register_my_new_order_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-invoiced', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Invoiced', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Invoiced <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Invoiced<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'my_new_wc_order_statuses' );

// Register in wc_order_statuses.
function my_new_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-invoiced'] = _x( 'Invoiced', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );

    return $order_statuses;
}
```

In order to add your new status to the admin Bulk-edit dropdown you have to use javascript.
Add your function to the `admin_footer` action.
My function then looks something like this:

```
function custom_bulk_admin_footer() {
            global $post_type;

            if ( $post_type == 'shop_order' ) {
                ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                            jQuery('<option>').val('mark_invoiced').text('<?php _e( 'Mark invoiced', 'textdomain' ); ?>').appendTo("select[name='action']");
                            jQuery('<option>').val('mark_invoiced').text('<?php _e( 'Mark invoiced', 'textdomain' ); ?>').appendTo("select[name='action2']");   
                        });
                    </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
```

The action is added two times because there are one bulk action at the top and another at the bottom of the order list.

Comment: @AparnaMathew glad it is working. :)

Comment: This adds it to the single order screen, and once you mark an order as this new order status, you get the navigation above the order list (ie, All, Mine, Pending, etc.) but it doesn't add it to the Bulk dropdown editor. Any ideas there, @Magnetize ?

Comment: @Nathan Hi there!
I do actually, but you have to add the bulk actions via js. 
Edited my answer as it is too long for a comment.

Comment: Does this still apply to WooCommerce 3.x ?

Comment: @Amjad indeed it does, I'm using it as we speak. :)

Comment: Indeed it works on 3.x as well. Thanks @Magnetize!

Comment: And what about to make the sum for orders in WooCommerce dashboard?

Answer (score 4):

As a completion for above and to not use JavaScript to add the actions in bulk actions list, to add/reorder bulk actions you can use the hook  `bulk_actions-edit-shop_order`. For example:

```
function rename_or_reorder_bulk_actions( $actions ) {
    $actions = array(
        // this is the order in which the actions are displayed; you can switch them
        'mark_processing'      => __( 'Mark placed', 'textdomain' ), // rewrite an existing status
        'mark_invoiced'        => __( 'Mark invoiced', 'textdomain' ), // adding a new one
        'mark_completed'       => $actions['mark_completed'],
        'remove_personal_data' => $actions['remove_personal_data'],
        'trash'                => $actions['trash'],
    );
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'rename_or_reorder_bulk_actions', 20 );
```

Cheers!