# where is admin footer?

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, order

hi im working on my new wordpress website. and i wanted to add custom order status in my woocommerce order status and i found this code:-

```
function custom_bulk_admin_footer() {
            global $post_type;

            if ( $post_type == 'shop_order' ) {
                ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                            jQuery('<option>').val('mark_invoiced').text('<?php _e( 'Mark invoiced', 'textdomain' ); ?>').appendTo("select[name='action']");
                            jQuery('<option>').val('mark_invoiced').text('<?php _e( 'Mark invoiced', 'textdomain' ); ?>').appendTo("select[name='action2']");   
                        });
                    </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
```

the question is , where should i put the code ? should i put it in my theme function.php ? or put it in admin_footer? if so can someone navigate me to the admin_footer section?

Comment: The problem here is that you have the function, but no action hook - your function will execute where you tell it to, providing you have the correct information.  What you need to find is the WooCommerce hook that best suits where this should be placed.  Then it'll be `add_action( 'the_woocommerce_hook', 'custom_bulk_admin_footer' ); ` You would then place it all in your functions.php.  Additionally, make sure you updated the function name to something unique and also make sure your `textdomain` matches your theme's `textdomain`.

Answer (score 0):

So the question that you found this code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199289/how-to-create-a-custom-order-status-in-woocommerce) says that they added this to the `admin_footer` action. So you could add that `custom_bulk_admin_footer` to your functions.php, and then hook it into the admin_footer action with this after the function:

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_bulk_admin_footer');
```

Obviously you need to change the jQuery code to do what you want inside the function too ;-)

HTH