# Order with custom order status disappeared once the page is refreshed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have added a custom order status based on following link :
[How to create a custom order status in woocommerce!](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199289/how-to-create-a-custom-order-status-in-woocommerce)

The custom order status that I created is 'outToDelivery'. Now for a new order I changed the status as follow : onHold --> Processing --> outToDelivery

However when the custom order status 'outToDelivery' is set for a particular order and the order page is refreshed, the order is disappeared from the order list.

Do we need to do something extra for latest version of Woocommerce (Version 5.8.0) to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I was using add_filter() instead of add_action() in 'init' hook.

The following link is the perfect solution for adding custom order status and email notification. My Woocommerce version is Version 5.8.0.

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/woocommerce_email_actions

The code snippet is as below :

```
// Add custom status to order list
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status', 10 );
function register_custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-tree', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Waiting in tree', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Waiting in tree <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Waiting in tree <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

// Add custom status to order page drop down
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses' );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-tree'] = _x( 'Waiting in tree', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
// Adding custom status 'tree' to admin order list bulk dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $actions['mark_tree'] = __( 'Mark Waiting in tree', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}

// Enable the action
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions' );
function filter_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-tree';
    return $actions;
}

// Send Customer Processing Order email notification when order status get changed from "tree" to "processing"
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'custom_status_email_notifications', 20, 4 );
function custom_status_email_notifications( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if ( $old_status == 'tree' && $new_status == 'processing' ) {
        // Get all WC_Email instance objects
        $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
        // Sending Customer Processing Order email notification
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
    }
}
```